# ¿Cómo duplicar registros cambiando algunos campos de 2 tablas en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, trigger

Llevo unas 4 h intentando llevar a cabo esta consulta

La idea es duplicar una materia que contiene temas, solo deseo cambiar el `Codigo` y `Nombre` de la materia. Lo que he logrado bajo lo que he podido investigar es lo siguiente:

```
-- Digite código de la materia a duplicar y el código de materia creada
set @MateriaAnterior = 1;
set @MateriaNueva = 9;

INSERT INTO temas_materias
(Puesto, CodiMate, Materia) 
  SELECT tm.Puesto, @MateriaNueva AS Codigo, mat.Nombre
    FROM temas_materias AS tm
    JOIN materias AS mat 
        ON (mat.Codigo=@MateriaNueva)
    WHERE mat.Codigo=tm.CodiMate
```

La consulta `SELECT` funciona correctamente, incluso podría decir que toda la consulta es correcta, pero tengo un problema con el que no tengo forma de encontrar una solución. El error trata de un `Trigger` que contiene la tabla `temas_materias` que inserta algunos registros por defecto (Temas de bienvenida a la materia). El error de la consulta en phpmyadmin es lo siguiente:

```
MySQL ha dicho:

#1442 - Can't update table 'materias' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger
```

**Actualización**
Tengo 2 triggers:
[image: Numero de modulos delete]
[image: Numero de modulos insert]

Tenga en cuenta que soy "Junior" o menos.
Agradezco mucho la atención prestada.

Comment: tu trigger sobre la tabla materias trata de actualizar la tabla materias??? entonces, entrariamos en un loop infinito?? en que momento se ejecuta tu trigger? podrias ponernos como lo definiste?

Comment: @gbianchi ¿Podrías revisar las capturas que realicé?, actualicé el enunciado.

Comment: Es que desde el inicio no tiene sentido, cada que eliminas e insertas un nuevo registro en la tabla temas_materias vas a realizar el mismo script? además, el error viene porque se identifica que la tabla se está usando en un mismo "lado" dos veces y no puede ser así.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solución

Logré llegar a la solución con el siguiente código SQL (*Lo dejaré comentado para dar una explicación un poco más detallada*):

```
-- Digite código de la materia a duplicar y el código de materia creada
set @MateriaAnterior = 1;
set @MateriaNueva = 9;

-- Guardo el nombre de la materia
set @NombreMateria = (SELECT Nombre FROM materias WHERE Codigo=@MateriaNueva LIMIT 1);

-- Borro los registros insertados por los triggers
DELETE FROM temas_materias WHERE CodiMate = @MateriaNueva;

-- Inserto los mismos registros que la otra materia cambiándole sólo el Código y Nombre de la materia
INSERT INTO temas_materias
  SELECT NULL, tm.Puesto, @MateriaNueva AS Codigo, @NombreMateria
    FROM temas_materias AS tm
    WHERE tm.CodiMate = @MateriaAnterior;
```

El problema que tenía con los triggers los ocasionaba el último `SELECT` cuando añadía un `JOIN` para traerme el nombre de la materia. Una vez hallado el conflicto, guardé el nombre de la materia en una variable y simplemente lo imprimí en la consulta como si fuese un `String` normal.

### ¡ADVERTENCIA!

Este código SQL lo elaboré para que fuese ejecutado provisionalmente en la consola de phpmyadmin para duplicar materias y ponerle otro nombre ejemplo *Matemáticas - Diurna* y *Matemáticas - Nocturna*.

Usa este ejemplo para entender conceptos como variables en SQL, guardar resultado de consulta en una variable, usar variables en consultas, duplicar registros combinando `INSERT` y `SELECT`, etc...

Este código puede mejorar si un experto nos regala algo de retroalimentación.

> Agradezco mucho la atención principalmente de los que comentaron y los
> que le echaron un vistazo para intentar dar una solución.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.